# Visual Studio SQL Server Object Explorer Not Saving Connections

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 for development. I really like using the SQL Server Object Explorer to work on database related tasks (queries, schema changes etc.). The issue is, every time I reload the IDE, I have to connect to the databases I work with. Is there a way to persist the list of databases like I can with the Server Explorer tab?

Comment: I'd also like to know where these settings are stored. I've had this issue in VS2012, VS2013, and VS2015. I haven't spent enough time in VS2017 to know whether it's still an issue but it's very annoying.

Comment: Did you find out where the previous connections are stored/cached?

Comment: Well, for whatever it's worth, it still happens in VS2017, too. Anyone following this can upvote the problem on the VS issue-reporting site [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/55130/visual-studio-2017-sql-server-object-explorer-serv.html).

Answer (score 2):

When you say you can't replicate, how long have you been using the explorer for to attempt to replicate it? It only loses the connections every now and then, so in fact right now I can't replicate it either, but over the next few days I'm sure they will get reset again!

> > It seems that there is something wrong with your VS IDE

It seems that this is a little bit unlikely as the same thing happened to me when I was running in VS 2012 beta running on Win 8 Release Preview too.

However I will try your suggestions and i'll see what happens, just to clarify are you saying that I run those commands once and then after that use VS as usual or are you saying that I try running in safe mode all the time?

Is reset settings same as the Import and Export settings->Reset All Settings menu item? (By the way I run with general development settings)

Anyone know where these connection settings are actually stored (registry, folder ...)?

Answer (score 2):

Open VS. Don´t open any project or solution.
Add your databases in the Server Explorer.
Then File -> Save All